# AlertDialog.Builder doesn't show

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-alertdialog

I am currently developing an Android app and I want to check if the contact picked from Contacts exists already in the database (meaning that he is already an user of the app) and if he exists to add him in a list.
I am using Firebase Realtime Database and my problem is that I am trying to display an AlertDialog if the users is not found in database and it doesn't show.

I mention that the code works: it is adding the contact in list if he exists in the database and it s not adding the contact if he's not, but my AlertDialog is not showing.

This is what I've tried until now:

```
users_table.orderByChild("phoneNumber").equalTo(phoneNumber).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                if(data.exists()){
                                    participantsList.add(user);
                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                }else if(!data.exists()){

                                 new AlertDialog.Builder(AddParticipants_Fragmnet.this.getContext())
                                            .setMessage(name + " is not a member of our app")
                                            .setTitle("Warning")
                                            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                                }
                                            }).show();


                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }});
```

Comment: can you debug your app and check if enters the condition `else if(!data.exists()){`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a AlertDialog.Builder, build it up with what you want; and then call create() before you call show(). Might look something like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AddParticipants_Fragmnet.this.getContext());
builder.setMessage(name + " is not a member of our app")
builder.setTitle("Warning")
builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", 
         new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
             }
         });
AlertDialog mdialog = builder.create();
mdialog.show();
```